# ST_Buffer with segment AND endcap parameters

Tags: qgis, postgis, sql, buffer

Making a QGis plugin that buffers a line and I want to declare a high number of segments and a flat endcap.

```
ST_Buffer(geom, 40, 25, 'endcap=flat')
```

This doesn't work with both parameters entered, it seems I can only choose one or the other.

How can I, if I can, choose both?

Current versions of both pieces of software.

Comment: There is no form of the [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html)function that takes 4 paramters, and end cap flat and many segments in a circular segment are probably logically inconsistent.

Comment: I guess the only way to accomplish this is to build the buffer geom in pyqgs and then pas the geometry to PostGIS ??